# Same origin policy in http

Tags: http, server, same-origin-policy

I was reading [An overview of HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) on MDN. There, it was said the Same Origin Policy is a burden on the sever:

> To prevent snooping and other privacy invasions, Web browsers enforce strict separation between Web sites. Only pages from the same origin can access all the information of a Web page. Though such constraint is a burden to the server, HTTP headers can relax this strict separation on the server side, allowing a document to become a patchwork of information sourced from different domains; there could even be security-related reasons to do so.

What I don't understand is how this filtering of request to server is costly for server and how HTTP is relaxing this processing. Please explain the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you, the Same Origin Policy isn't a burden on the *server* in particular.

I suspect that the author of that sentence is trying to communicate that the Same Origin Policy can be a burden on *web sites* more generally, since it rules out or complicates valid use cases; and that that burden was eased by the introduction of CORS.

Remember that MDN is just a wiki, there's nothing authoritative about it.